# CSS Grid: lines with labels

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm building a pure css chart using css-grid. Is there a way to label the grid lines with text? In the attached image, I want to label the vertical lines: 1, 2, 3, 4.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/geoquant-the-sans/pen/YobGXp)

```
grid-template-columns: 150px repeat(12, 1fr);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post your html code?

Comment: added the example i'm working with @NenadVracar

Answer (score 2):

You could use `:after` pseudo element to add numbers for each line and you can use css counter to increment number for each column based on the number of element in the first row.

You can start the counter from 1 instead of 0 by defining the second parameter on `counter-reset` which is the number.

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  position: relative;
  counter-reset: columnLines 1 rowLines 1;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 25px;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  counter-increment: rowLines;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.row > div:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/*Column lines*/
.row:first-child:before {
  content: "1";
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.row:first-child > div {
  counter-increment: columnLines;
  position: relative;
}

.row:first-child > div:after{
  transform: translate(50%, -100%);
  content: counter(columnLines);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/*Row lines*/
.row:after {
  transform: translate(100%, 50%);
  content: counter(rowLines);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -5px;
}

.grid:before {
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  content: "1";
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```